# Error after connecting to server Pixel Streaming Unreal Engine

Tags: server, client-server, pixel, unreal-engine4

I have a problem related to connecting Signalling and Web Server to Matchmaker Server (Pixel Streaming, Unreal Engine 4). I have created Matchmaker Server using:

> run.bat --httpPort 88 --matchmakerPort 8888

I have created Signalling and Web Server using:

> run.bat --httpPort 10 --matchmakerPort 8888 --streamerPort 8880
> --matchmakerAddress 192.63.8.102 --publicIp 192.63.8.102 --UseMatchmaker

I can connect to the server, I have a signal inside Matchmaker. The problem is that when I try to run the game which has these attributes in shortcut:

> -AudioMixer -PixelStreamingIP=localhost -PixelStreamingPort=8888

I have an error:

> Ending connection to remote address ::1 ERROR (SyntaxError: Unexpected
> token G in JSON at position 0): Failed to parse Cirrus information
> from data: GET // HTTP/1.1 Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache
> Host: localhost Origin: http://localhost Upgrade: websocket
> Connection: Upgrade Sec-WebSocket-Key: 6Vq4v7dV2lwT6mA+WZUl3A==
> Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: ws Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13

How to fix it ? I did not change anything inside cirrus.js

Comment: Looks like you have a malformatted JSON somewhere: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token G in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: The HTTP port for the matchmaking server is 10, so you should be going to the address `<my ip>:10`. The server will then redirect you to available cirrus servers.

Comment: Also, as the other answer said, your pixel streaming port has to match the streamer port.

Answer (score 1):

pixelstreamingport of your ue app should be the same as streamingport of signalling server.